# Unable to run Live Server on 443 port

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveserver, vscode-plugin

I am using LiveServer plugin of VSCode to serve my pages. I need to serve it on port number 443.
Below is my settings.json file.

```
{
  "liveServer.settings.port": 443,
  "liveServer.settings.root": "/",
  "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
  "liveServer.settings.https": {
    "enable": true,
    "cert": "xxx/https/localhost.pem",
    "key": "xxx/localhost.key",
    "passphrase": "XXXXXX"
  } }
```

As soon as i run the server the port number automatically changes from 443 to 444. Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already have something listening on port 443

Answer (score 1):

If you use Windows, open Powershell and enter the following command:
Test-NetConnection -computername google.de -port 443

This will test if the port is free or not

Answer (score 0):

If you are running VSCode with WSL on windows, linux has a bind permission limitation for ports less than 1000, found https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bind-port-number-less-1024-non-root-access/ and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138064, haven't figured out a solution yet. Anyone who have a clue, please kindly share.